# exim filter regex discard rule

Tags: exim, regex, filter

We are trying to discard all emails with a matching subject, example of subject:

Subject: DOMAIN.COM Alert: NAME We have NOT received your payment

We are trying to match any domain, Alert, and "We have NOT received your payment"

Using the following filter:

```
if
 $header_subject: matches "^(?!:\\\\/\\\\/)([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\\\\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\\\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,11}?\\$"
 and $header_subject: contains "Alert"
 and $header_subject: contains "We have NOT received your payment"
then
 save "/dev/null" 660
endif
```

Its not matching however when testing, I've tested the regex to match domain and it is working, but when adding the additional rules, it stops the filter from working.

Answer (score 0):

**This discards mail with a subject matching "DOMAIN.COM Alert: NAME We have NOT received your payment"**

(where DOMAIN.COM can be any domain)

```
if $h_subject matches "^[A-Za-z0-9-_]+\\\\.[a-zA-Z]\\\\b.+Alert.+We have NOT received your payment\\$"
then
  seen finish
endif
```

Note: You can test a system filter's effect on delivery with:

```
exim -bF test_filter <test_message
```

Your first regex contains `\\$` which matches the end of string, so it only matches if the domain string is at the end of the subject.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working:

https://pastebin.com/6eGtkung